# Why does $x^2=a$ lead to $x=\pm\sqrt{a}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Why does $x^2=a$ lead to $x=\pm\sqrt{a}$?

Is it okay to say (which is obviously not true from a certain point of view): $x^2=a\to x=x \lor x=-x$?

$x, a\in\Bbb{R}$ and $x,a>0$

Comment: It's not okay to say that, it isn't true from any point of view that people here have :) $x=x$ is always true, and $x=-x$ is true only if $x=0$. It's ok to say $x = \sqrt a \vee x=-\sqrt a$, which is exactly what "$x=± \sqrt a$" means.

Comment: see my post at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1499941/is-there-a-difference-between-x-frac1n-and-sqrtnx/1517550#1517550

Comment: How to explain it simply? @MichaelMedvinsky Your answer seems to be an overkill for such a simple question.

Comment: It is actually not that simple question, since many people get struggled with it.
Simple\short: $x^2$ isn't one-to-one in $\mathbb{R}$ and therefore have no inverse function in  $\mathbb{R}$. It has inverse function in $[0,\infty)$ and in $(-\infty,0]$ therefore when you need an inverse you have to split it into two cases one per each of these domains.

Comment: As simply as I can say it: for any $a>0$ there are two $x$ such that $x^2 = a$, one positive and the other negative. The positive one is denoted by $\sqrt a$, and the negative one is $-\sqrt a$.

Comment: @BrianO You are right that $x=-x$ is rarely true, but one may argue that $x = \sqrt a \vee x=-\sqrt a$ is also not always true. It is true for the reals, but not for the complex numbers. On the other hand $x^2=a\to x=x \lor x=-x$ is true in $\mathbb Z_2$ (admittedly in a rather not very interesting way, namely $x^2=a\to x=x \land x=-x$ :)

Comment: @Mirko can you show me such a complex number $x\ne0$ which have a property $x=-x$?

Comment: @Mirko Actually $x^2=a \to x=x \lor x=-x$ is true in any structure where the operations $x^2$ and $-x$ exist, it's a valid formula because of $x=x$. More to the point, though, it's not the correct conclusion, $x=±\sqrt a$ is just a shorthand, it does **not** mean or imply that $\sqrt a = -\sqrt a$ for any $a>0$.

Comment: @Joe So, things are clearer now? or less clear? I'd believe either outcome.

Comment: the statement like $x=x \land x=-x$ mean $x=-x$ since the other part is trivial. So, this statement imply $x=0$, When you put it in 
$x^2=a\to x=x \land x=-x$  it looks very incorrect and may have an impression that $a=0$, which isn't what you want to say here. The statement $x = \sqrt a \vee x=-\sqrt a$ is more appropriate. Also, I didn't get what is wrong with complex numbers.

Comment: @MichaelMedvinsky Yes, you caught an error in my comment, thank you! I was thinking that $x^2=|a|\not\to x=x \lor x=-x$ for complex numbers, but the question didn't use $|a|$, so I was wrong. On the other hand it is interesting to read how everybody has their opinion as to what he question meant to ask ... strictly it does not specify that we consider the reals, and formally it is ok to say $x^2=a\to x=x \lor x=-x$ as it is a tautology ... though people seem to try to guess the "level" of OP and tailor their answer accordingly (guessing what was meant to be asked, but wasn't).

Comment: See the update, I've added the constraints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $a>0$ and think like this: $$x^2 = a \stackrel{\sqrt{\cdot}}{\implies} \sqrt{x^2} = \sqrt{a} \implies |x| = \sqrt{a} \implies x = \sqrt{a} \text{   or  } x = -\sqrt{a}.$$

Comment: Consider my edit. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

even simpler $x^2=a\Rightarrow (\pm x)^2=a\Rightarrow \pm x=\sqrt{a}\Rightarrow x=\pm \sqrt{a}$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is ok to say that $x^2=a\to x=x \lor x=-x$, as it is a tautology, i.e. it is always true, as @BrianO noted in the first comment (regardless that somewhat confusingly he says "isn't true" ... "is always true" :).

Logically (disregarding any properties of numbers in any algebraic system), 
$x=x$ is true, hence $x=x \lor P$ is true for any property $P$, hence $Q\to x=x \lor P$ is also true, for any $P$ and any $Q$.

Here is a bit convoluted answer to the first part of the question assuming we work with the real numbers. It is easier for me to consider the contrapositive. Suppose that $x\not=\pm\sqrt{a}$ (where $a\ge0$). Then either $x<-\sqrt{a}$ or $-\sqrt{a} < x < \sqrt{a}$, or $\sqrt{a} < x$. 
If $x<-\sqrt{a}$ or if $\sqrt{a} < x$ then $x^2>a$. If $-\sqrt{a} < x < \sqrt{a}$ then $x^2<a$. So $x^2\not=a$.